# I need help for symbol +=

Tags: java, c++

I am beginner and I want ask the meaning of this symbol:

I know that this:

**i++**  ------> is this **i=i+1**

but this:

**+=**  -------> what is?

Do you know other rare symbols (aka operators)?

Comment: The term for these types of symbols is operators. If you're trying to find information on them it can be hard because if you search for `+=` you may get no results. Use the actual words for the symbols when you search. So using this operator as an example, if you search for `java plus equals` you'll get what you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
x+=y
```

is not a rare piece of notation at all. It's just a shortened version of the following:

```
x = x + y
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a shorter variant of base math function.

```
a += 5   =>   a = a + 5;
a += 1   =>   a = a + 1   =>   a++ // special case of the code abode, incrementation is allowed by this shorter code

a *= 2   =>   a = a * 2

a -= 1   =>   a = a - 1   =>   a--
a -= 2   =>   a = a - 2
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Some time we need to modify same variable value and reassigned it to same reference variable. Java allows you to combine assignment and addition operators using a **shorthand operator**. For example, the preceding statement can be written as:

```
i +=8; //This is same as i = i+8;
```

+= goes under assignment operator category like

```
 += -= *= /= %= &= ^= |= <<= >>= >>>=
```

means

`+=` addition and assignment operator

`x +=y;` as same as `x= x+y;`

Answer (score 0):

i++, i=i+1, and i+=1 are all the same thing.